# Force PDF to download using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, browser, download, cross-browser

Working on a client's site and it is just not cooperating.  I have tried things many different edits in the .htaccess to get the pdf to download.

Almost every edit I do turns into a 500 internal server error.

I had it working in firefox and safari.  But in chrome it won't do anything, and ie8 it downloads in the same tab.

Numerous complaints and I just cannot figure it out.

The website is www.kahlenberg.com  An example where you can find a pdf is kahlenberg.com/sound.html

Thank you ahead of time.

[image: Wireshark]

You can also open the wireshark file from this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z91ma58be47xkv3/wireshark

Comment: I was able to download the catalogue with no problem... can you give a specific link that is not working?

Comment: Can you post your current .htaccess

Comment: @Reinderien All of them fail in Chrome.  Seems the only way to download them is via right click save link as.

Comment: @UlrichPalha AddType application/octet-stream .pdf   -- This is making FF and Safari work.  But Chrome still fails to open it, and ie8 opens it in the same tab.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758866/257319

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying these to see what effects they have:
http://mimeapplication.net/pdf

Failing that, you should dig deeper. Fire up Wireshark and compare the headers from a captured HTTP packet for a good online PDF versus a bad online PDF. The answer is likely to be in there.

Comment: I ran it through wireshark like reinderien suggested, and we're getting a [Malformed Packet: Gif Image] when I do a capture in Firefox, it transfers just fine and nothing weird shows up in Wireshark. I've done my Google-fu, and nothing turns up. I guess it's downloading as a gif? I don't know. If anyone could help, I'd love it. Thanks

Comment: Could you attach the capture to your question?